# installing Emacs 24.4 from source on CentOS5 with libpng12

Tags: emacs24.4

When trying to install the new emacs I'm getting an error about libpng15 being missing:

```
$ ./configure
...
$ make all
...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng15
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have libpng12 installed. How can I make emacs use that library instead?

Below is the configuration output of `./configure`.

```
Configured for `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'.

  Where should the build process find the source code?    .
  What compiler should emacs be built with?               gcc -std=gnu99 -g3 -O2
  Should Emacs use the GNU version of malloc?             yes
      (Using Doug Lea's new malloc from the GNU C Library.)
  Should Emacs use a relocating allocator for buffers?    no
  Should Emacs use mmap(2) for buffer allocation?         no
  What window system should Emacs use?                    x11
  What toolkit should Emacs use?                          GTK2
  Where do we find X Windows header files?                Standard dirs
  Where do we find X Windows libraries?                   Standard dirs
  Does Emacs use -lXaw3d?                                 no
  Does Emacs use -lXpm?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -ljpeg?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -ltiff?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use a gif library?                           yes -lgif
  Does Emacs use a png library?                           yes -lpng15 -lz -lm
  Does Emacs use -lrsvg-2?                                no
  Does Emacs use imagemagick?                             no
  Does Emacs support sound?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgpm?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -ldbus?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -lgconf?                                 yes
  Does Emacs use GSettings?                               no
  Does Emacs use a file notification library?             yes -lgio (gfile)
  Does Emacs use access control lists?                    no
  Does Emacs use -lselinux?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgnutls?                                yes
  Does Emacs use -lxml2?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -lfreetype?                              yes
  Does Emacs use -lm17n-flt?                              no
  Does Emacs use -lotf?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -lxft?                                   yes
  Does Emacs directly use zlib?                           yes
  Does Emacs use toolkit scroll bars?                     yes
```

ImageMagick is installed, so I'm not sure why Emacs doesn't see that. But more importantly, Emacs seems to think the libpng15 is available.

And earlier...

```
checking png.h usability... yes
checking png.h presence... yes
checking for png.h... yes
checking for png_get_channels in -lpng... yes
checking whether png_longjmp is declared... no
```

Comment: Maybe the `libpng12-dev` library is needed? Didn't `./configure` report anything regarding `libpng12`?

Comment: nope. See that output above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suffered from the same situation.
Investigating in the **configure.ac** file reveals that the configure script in my case got the -lpng15 from the invocation of the *libpng-config* utility:

```
dnl Some systems, eg NetBSD 6, only provide eg "libpng16", not "libpng".
lpng=`libpng-config --libs 2> /dev/null`
case $lpng in
  -l*) : ;;
  *) lpng="-lpng" ;;
esac
LIBPNG="$lpng -lz -lm"
```

Checking for the result that the utility yields, confirms the source of the link flag. In my case the error is due to a libpng installation from my external anaconda environment that gets mixed up with the build (and the anaconda env lacks the dev files for building... else it probably would have worked).

```
~/desk/emacs-24.4$ libpng-config --libs
   -lpng15
~/desk/emacs-24.4$ which libpng-config
   /opt/anaconda/python2.7/bin/libpng-config
```

So, my guess is that you also should have a look at the PATH settings of your build environment and test where the libpng-config comes from. Correct it and then re-run configure.

After correcting the PATH my build works cleanly.

Good luck!

Comment: anaconda is responsible for my issue as well.

Comment: The same problem occurs in Ubuntu 14.10 when installing emacs24.4 if anaconda is installed. The answer by dfeich works - thanks! Move .bashrc to .bashrc_bak and remove the references to anaconda from the path in .bashrc. Start a new terminal window to do the build. Then mv .bashrc_bak to .bashrc.

Comment: Throw in Canopy/Enthought. Got this error on a 25.1 configure on U16.04. Comment out all your Canopy lines (2 lines in my .bashrc).